# Cannot get react-router to work after upgrade

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been working on upgrading our app from React.js 0.13 to 15.4.2 and the dependencies surrounding it. I might be close, but after 50 hours over 4 days, I am at the end, my last hope.

In the upgrade the react-router is upgraded to version 4.0.0 and every documentation and tutorial and stack over flow question showing how to write the router (all the same so must be correct) however, when I do it that way it always fails. Either saying history is a required attribute, or when I add it via the samples it still comes up as undefined and an error.

Here is our index.js with the router.

Can anyone see where I am not getting it correct? Thanks

import React from 'react';

```
// material ui
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Theme from './styles/theme.js';

import Header from './components/header.jsx';
import Home from './views/home.jsx';

import CaseController from 'controllers/caseController';
import LoginController from 'controllers/loginController';
import XController from 'controllers/xController';
import PredefinedSearchAssetCasesController from 'controllers/predefinedSearchAssetCasesController';
import PredefinedSearchCaseLabelsController from 'controllers/predefinedSearchCaseLabelsController';
import DeepSearchController from 'controllers/deepSearchController';
import NamesAndAddressController from 'controllers/namesAndAddressController';
import AccountListing from 'controllers/accountListingController';

import LoginStore from 'stores/loginStore';
import LoginActions from 'actions/loginActions';
import UtcStore from 'stores/utcStore';
import UtcActions from 'actions/utcActions';

import ErrorHandler from 'components/errorHandler';
import DialogMessageHandler from 'components/dialogMessageHandler';
import ConfirmationDialogHandler from 'components/confirmationDialogHandler';

// routing related
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, DefaultRoute, Link, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import versionNumber from 'raw-loader!../.version';

var App = React.createClass ({

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: MuiThemeProvider.get()
    };
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    //ThemeManager.setTheme(Theme);
    // TODO: consolidate into one request using /utc endpoint
    if (_.isEmpty(UtcStore.claimUtcList)) {
      UtcActions.getClaimUtcList();
    }
    if (_.isEmpty(UtcStore.assetUtcList)) {
      UtcActions.getAssetUtcList();
    }
    if (_.isEmpty(UtcStore.transferUtcList)) {
      UtcActions.getTransfers();
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    LoginStore.addChangeListener(this.onLoginChange);
    if (!LoginStore.getLoginData()){
      this.transitionTo('login');
      return false;
    } else {
      LoginActions.checkToken();
    }
  },

  onLoginChange(){
    if (!LoginStore.getLoginData()){
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  },

  render() {

    console.log('VERSION: ', versionNumber);

    const styles = {
      root: {
        background: '#EEEEEE',
        paddingTop: 55 // see header.jsx menuHeight
      }
    };

    console.log('APP', this.context.router.getCurrentPath());

    let hideHeaderRoutes = ["/login"];
    let header = true;
    if (this.context.router.getCurrentPath().indexOf(hideHeaderRoutes) > -1){
      header = false;
      styles.root = undefined;
    }

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={Theme}>
        <div style={styles.root}>
          {header ? <Header /> : {}}

          <ErrorHandler
            ref="errorHandler"
            />
          <DialogMessageHandler
            ref="dialogMessageHandler"
            />
          <ConfirmationDialogHandler
            ref="confirmDialogHandler"
            />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
});

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App} path="/">
      <DefaultRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="case" component={CaseController} />
      <Route path="case/:id/?:reverseToken?" component={CaseController} /> /* reverseToken is optional path variable for going back to last state when we go to case screen*/
      <Route path="login" component={LoginController} />
      <Route path="x" component={XController} />
      <Route path="x/?:xDate?/?:xFromTime?/?:xToTime?/?:id?" component={XController} />
      <Route path="namesAndAddress" component={NamesAndAddressController} />
      <Route path="reconciliation/?:reverseToken?" component={AccountListing} />
      <Route path="asset-cases/:predefinedQuery/:sortBy/?:reverseToken?" component={PredefinedSearchAssetCasesController} />
      <Route path="case-labels/:predefinedQuery/:sortBy/?:reverseToken?" component={PredefinedSearchCaseLabelsController} />
      <Route path="deep-search/:deepSearchQuery/:sortBy/openCasesOnly::openCasesOnly/assetCasesOnly::assetCasesOnly/searchType::searchType/?:reverseToken?" component={DeepSearchController} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the History objects are no longer a part of react-router. So, you're `import { Router, Route, DefaultRoute, Link, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';` isn't actually importing hashHistory or browserHistory.

Based on the [examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router), one solution to get a history object is to install the [`history/createBrowserHistory` package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James. I tried that and got errors from history, that the createBrowserHistory point to es.createBrowserHistory which had an error in it. And it appears too the react-router no longer has <Router> tag, so I think I have to back version it. And react-router 4 now no longer has static routing, there is a beta module for it, but it is so convoluted that you can't make any sense of its documentation.

Comment: Did you try the BrowserRouter? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is there is no answer, that react-router 4.00 needs react-router-config to do static routing like you could in earlier version. So all the code above in the question is meaningless.

Comment: Did you check out [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config)? It doesn't mention the extra module. The [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) is also pretty similar to your configuration above. After going through this conversion process a while back, I can relate with your challenges :). All the best!

Comment: Thanks HazardouS, in the first example they aren't setting the Router's mandatory history attribute. The second example is using the newest 1 week old version of 4.0.0 which I have learned is not able to do static routing unless it is using their Alpha version of react-router-config, which has no documentation and I have been told by them that the API will change too because it is Alpha. So I do need to downgrade my upgrade to version 3.0.

Comment: The documentation will catch up in a while. Would it be possible to take a look at your repo?

Comment: If you mean our businesses codebase repo? No, we write legal software that is unavailable to the public. I just updated the question with a screenshot. as I have downgraded to 3.0.0 and I think it is close, but just not working yet. Getting a browser error on Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined.

Comment: OK got past that error. I was using <DefaultRoute> which no longer exists and just used <Route>. Next issue is the context.router thing, which I know I saw something on this elsewhere that there is another way to get it.

Comment: Use the `withRouter` hoc to inject context in any component you need it.

Comment: Migration from v3 to v4 should be easier when you get there.

Comment: Thanks, I am now past what I think is my react-router issues, as I get a new error not related to react-router but on the changes to React theme provider from 0.13 to 15.4.2 :D Thanks for your help HazardouS